# Problem with sendrawtransaction

Tags: bitcoind, testnet, raw-transaction, rpc-error-25

When I use bitcoin-cli sendrawtransaction and only get -25 errors. I have tried to push the transaction using different blockchain explorer sites, but that didn't work. I have tried:

0100000001659d0ebe45e4446113776807a0160ab487a56f8386405e07d8d15275f18bb832010000006b483045022100e642093c9a56c76aeae91c68c19fd3f5f487d9d63c4f07259c5899a4df6f9bdf02203228b7f33a662fd5f3dc6fb3c361169392f91f74fe82ada1ce09bae55720ece70121029e033dda03e6cf9e0c93ac5b2689d047fd8e559ea0b5cfd1c86062387c672dcdffffffff0180d1f008000000001976a91476d2d121a1bbbc7e4c51f7a7c84437bb3aa1d66d88ac00000000

at
https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/pushtx/
it decodes well, I get the message  "Transaction Successfully Broadcst"
but at the same time:

" No transaction found with the hash 7f1aa3a20163a9d4058940dd6af29b3f7aefc037b2f3b21133a1413a990bc4e7"

I can send transactions using sendtoaddress and this seems equivalent. I started from:
https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/tx/32b88bf17552d1d8075e4086836fa587b40a16a0076877136144e445be0e9d65/
used:

bitcoin-cli createrawtransaction '[{"txid": "32b88bf17552d1d8075e4086836fa587b40a16a0076877136144e445be0e9d65", "vout": 1}]' '{"mrMEaWKfkJZcAN52VqNxKkF21uvf9HF9G7":1.5}'

0100000001659d0ebe45e4446113776807a0160ab487a56f8386405e07d8d15275f18bb8320100000000ffffffff0180d1f008000000001976a91476d2d121a1bbbc7e4c51f7a7c84437bb3aa1d66d88ac00000000

bitcoin-cli signrawtransaction 0100000001659d0ebe45e4446113776807a0160ab487a56f8386405e07d8d15275f18bb8320100000000ffffffff0180d1f008000000001976a91476d2d121a1bbbc7e4c51f7a7c84437bb3aa1d66d88ac00000000
{
    "hex" : "0100000001659d0ebe45e4446113776807a0160ab487a56f8386405e07d8d15275f18bb832010000006b483045022100c139f0601bcef52dca990a7a5ae73a6e30ce5f521e2be25e80376338c4d0a84a02201f691b9295c32660d023ff65e8b2793b563f29b66d0c704577785d353e2f66620121029e033dda03e6cf9e0c93ac5b2689d047fd8e559ea0b5cfd1c86062387c672dcdffffffff0180d1f008000000001976a91476d2d121a1bbbc7e4c51f7a7c84437bb3aa1d66d88ac00000000",
    "complete" : true
}

It decodes, can be signed, I have funds and I've sent similar transactions before, but now seems impossible.

Comment: Error -25 can be generated by your own client, even before it tries to send it to the network at all.  So I would think it's more likely that there is something wrong with your transaction, and the network is fine.  Perhaps you could explain in detail how you created the transaction.

Comment: Your last question (having to recheck blocks) is almost certainly a problem at your end, and unrelated to your transactions being rejected. You should ask it as a separate question, including the exact message (we can't guess much from "I get an error") and details about how you shut down the client previously.

Comment: Agreed. They are unrelated problems. I will leave the question for the rawtransaction and see if I can reproduce the other problem for another question. I was seeing strange things and started to think everything was connected. My bad. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your posted transaction has a tx fee of 0.5 XTN:

```
Version:  1  tx hash 7f1aa3a20163a9d4058940dd6af29b3f7aefc037b2f3b21133a1413a990bc4e7  192 bytes   
TxIn count: 1; TxOut count: 1
Lock time: 0 (valid anytime)
Input:
   0: mjKj3fFKUBMfYiozTw4jngpuDQRjarn62F from 32b88bf17552d1d8075e4086836fa587b40a16a0076877136144e445be0e9d65:1      2000.00000 mBTC  sig ok
Output:
   0: mrMEaWKfkJZcAN52VqNxKkF21uvf9HF9G7 receives   1500.00000 mBTC
Total input    2000.00000 mBTC
Total output   1500.00000 mBTC
Total fees      500.00000 mBTC
```

which exceeds the default max [imposed by Bitcoin Core](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/11855c1f990a4a66f55de60a30a8898ccbf766ec) of [0.1 XTN (or BTC)](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.10.2/src/wallet.h#L44). Please try adding the `-maxtxfee=<amt>` option to bitcoind's command line, and report back if you're still having difficulty.

Comment: That was exactly the problem! Thank you! I will modify the question to make everything clear.

Comment: @halftimepad you can also add the second parameter to `sendrawtransaction`, which is a boolean for `allowhighfees`.

Comment: @StephenM347 I did not know that, thanks!

Comment: @StephenM347 Great! I'll also try some high fee transactions then. Last time I sent raw transactions there was no fee limit (and lost a few testnet coins in the changes).